# Is it an hardware or software issue

Tags: samsung

I rooted my android phone using MTK,then it started displaying horizontal shaking lines,and the phone didn't fall or crack,Pls is that an hardware or software issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot of the screen. If it doesn't have the lines on it, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/125952)

Comment: Beeshyams, there is no way that they can tell whether the lines on the screen are hardware or software related without either taking a screenshot or watching the boot process.  My answer does provide a method that allows the OP's question to be solved. The OP also doesn't request a solution to fix the lines. If they want an answer to that, then they can edit their question as such.

Comment: Can you please quote reasons adequately supported by sources for your reasoning? That would differentiate between an answer and a suggestion/ opinion. Please do not misinterpret as a criticism on your attempt to answer but that is how answers are expected to be on this site. Please do look around and see other answers on site